# Discovering what moved an email to Outlook Deleted Items centrally in Office365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

We're using Office 365 and recently sent out an important email, which most users have not seen.  I have them examine their Deleted Items folder and discover it there, first time they've seen it.
Individual user rules don't appear to have moved the email in any case (the majority of the users I checked had no Rules anyway).  We have a Company-wide Rule matching the sending address, which Set the spam confidence level (SCL) to '-1' and set message header 'X-Forefront-Antispam-Report' with the value 'SFV:SKI'
Mail Trace shows the messages arriving successfully for all of these users, but then the trail grows cold.  Compliance Center eDiscovery shows no further useful info, but there may be features there I'm unfamiliar with.

How can I find out what is moving these emails to the Deleted Items folder?  My searches thus far have yielded results about recovering emails, but not how to determine what process deleted them.

Fundamentally, I need to ensure that future emails are actually seen, read, and interacted with by all of my users.  I can re-send the important email, but I want to ensure it doesn't just go straight to Deleted Items automatically.

Answer (score -2):

What are the characteristics of these messages that go into the deleted folder?

Is it from the same recipient?

As mentioned in this article, there seem to be many reasons：https://www.msoutlook.info/question/832

Hope that may help you!